# API call within script does not return expected value, script continues

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have api calls within scripts. The scripts then uses the information from the api calls. I think the problem is that *sometimes* the script moves on without waiting for a response from the api call. Here's the reason why I think this is the case:

Example 1: I have a script (cs.py) that gets the currency conversion rate with an api call and does some other stuff. Sometimes when I run this script I get an error that looks like the following.
`aud_to_usd = requests.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=AUD&symbols=USD').json()['rates']['USD']
...
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Example 2: I have a script that takes invoices and either extracts text using tika (if text is searchable) or extracts text using the google vision ocr api. The end result being text that is formatted and output into a spreadsheet. *Sometimes* only the text from the tika call appears in the spreadsheet, the info from the google api call just doesn't come through.

If I run the scripts incrementally in ipython (e.g., pasting each api call into the terminal individually and waiting for a response) the scripts work. Also (as hinted by my use of the word "sometimes") just running the entire script works, sometimes.

This seems like it would be a common issue. Am I right that the api call is just taking too long and the script is moving on? Is there a way to make the script wait until a response is provided? For example, a try-except that tries the api call, waits some amount of time and re-tries the call if there is no response?

(SO is telling me not to the use tag 'api' but I cannot think of a more appropriate tag...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. you can do something like this:

`exch_rate = None
while not exch_rate:
    try:
        resp = requests.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=AUD&symbols=USD')
        resp.raise_for_status()
        exch_rate = resp.json()
    except:
        time.sleep(5)`

You can also guard against timeouts like so: `requests.get('http://github.com', timeout=0.001)`

obviously I would suggest bailing out of the while loop after a  few failed tries :-)

Comment: I think it would be kind (and may avoid getting you banned from using their API), if you put in a sleep call after the try fails.

Comment: Great idea! adding